# What's the best approach to gauge Zabbix bandwidth consumption?

Tags: zabbix

How can we rough estimate the bandwidth Zabbix will be using to monitor an infra? It doesn't need to be strongly accurate, but at least to have some estimated numbers to work with.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't an answer.

Also, bandwidth should be of least concern, while the database and storage IOPS are usually the bottleneck of a big monitoring infrastructure.

However, I can get you some hints on sizing based on experience and [the documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/installation/requirements).

Zabbix "resource consumption" depends on the combination of hosts, items and their interval checks. This is usually referred as "New values per second": it's used for database sizing and as a quick view of "how much stuff am I reading".

So, monitor "an infra" could be any number of new values per second. Consider that a 96 port switch with L3 could spawn 800 items, most of them with a 60 second interval (so at least 13 nvps), while a simple ICMP check usually consists of 3 items with a 60 second interval (0.05 nvps).

How much bandwidth is needed for 1 new value per second depends on the check type:

- a snmp check should be 2 UDP packets
- a snmp discovery... who knows! it depends on the device itself
- a http check at least 5 TCP packets (syn, syn/ack, ack+piggyback, push, fin) if you want the headers only, many more if you are capturing a json or a full page
- an agent check... actually I did not measure it
- a custom script... who knows!

So as you can see the variables are too "variable" to be predictable.

My suggestion: start with a small Zabbix (even dockerized) and add one or two objects per type (2 windows server, 2 linux server, 2 switches, 2 ups etc..), let it run for a few days and use the estimated NVPS and items as a benchmark.

Then, depending on the size of the infrastructure, you should plan the production setup and select one of these configurations:

- 1 virtual machine with zabbix and the database
- 1 bare metal with zabbix and the database
- 1 virtual machine with zabbix with the database on your database server
- etc...

Hope it helps!